# Cannot get more than one port to be exposed with docker

Tags: docker

Im trying to get more than one port exposed with the docker run command.  The command I am running is 
`docker run -p --detach --publish 8055:80 8455:443 cptactionhank/atlassian-jira:latest`, but it gives me the error `docker: Invalid containerPort: --detach.`

If I then move the -p right before the container ports, I get `docker run --detach --publish -p 8055:80 8455:443 cptactionhank/atlassian-jira:latest` and get the same error - `docker: Invalid containerPort: -p.`

Am I missing something obvious here?  How can I get this command to work?

Trying `docker run -p 8055:80 -p 8455:443 --detach --publish cptactionhank/atlassian-jira:latest` gives me `docker: "run" requires a minimum of 1 argument.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need -p before every port.
Please try it that way:

```
docker run --detach -p 8055:80 -p 8455:443 cptactionhank/atlassian-jira:latest
```